# How to use CANopenLinux with USBtin?

Tags: can-bus, socketcan, canopen, canutils

I use the **USBtin** via `socketcan` by plugging in the device and executing `can-utils` on CentOS

```
sudo slcan_attach -f -s3 -o /dev/ttyACM0
sudo slcand ttyACM0 can0
sudo ip link set up can0
```

Then I check `ifconfig`

```
can0: flags=193<UP,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 16
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 10  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and I can use it just like **every other CAN device**

I set up a OD basic enough to compile the repository.

I have 2 devices, one with the **USBtin** and one Pi with another shield. While latter prints out the message as expected, I get a segmentation fault with **USBtin**

Pi output when executing `./canopend can0 -i 4`

```
./canopend[5490]: CANopen device, Node ID = 0x00, starting
./canopend[5490]: CAN Interface "can0" RX buffer set to 477 messages (212992 Bytes)
./canopend[5490]: CANopen NMT state changed to: "initializing" (0)
./canopend[5490]: CANopen device, Node ID = 0x04, communication reset
./canopend[5490]: CANopen device, Node ID = 0x04, running ...
./canopend[5490]: CANopen NMT state changed to: "pre-operational" (127)
./canopend[5490]: CANopen Emergency message from node 0x04: errorCode=0x5000, errorRegister=0x01, errorBit=0x2F, infoCode=0x00000004
```

Device with **USBtin** output when executing `./canopend can0 -i 1`

```
./canopend[4722]: CANopen device, Node ID = 0x00, starting
./canopend[4722]: CAN Interface "can0" RX buffer set to 477 messages (212992 Bytes)
./canopend[4722]: (main) CANopen error in CO_CANopenInit(), err=-1
./canopend[4722]: CANopen device, Node ID = 0x01, finished
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I was able to pin down the problem to the `CO_GTWA_init()` which is part of the `CiA 309` standard implementation.

As I did not set any flags regarding the `309`, the default flags will have been defined in `CO_driver_target`
[image]

As I did not define any GTW Config for the Pi either I wonder if the cause for the problem is not the missing GTW settings but the default GTW settings due to the slcan might requiring a specific configuration differently to the default `socketcan`?

As I do not have access to the `CiA 309` and I don't intend to use it, I wonder if I must get `309` due to the USBtin?

Does anyone know something about this problem?